# can't identify country code by typing country calling code using libphonenumber-js for US

Tags: javascript, libphonenumber

I'm using `libphonenubmer-js` in order to display the country flag while typing the phone number, on the country calling code step:

```
  const asYouType = new AsYouType();
  asYouType.input(`+${callingCode}`);

  console.log({ asYouType.country })
```

The problem is that for a french number (`+33 | 33` prefix), `FR` is identified immediately.
But for US (`+1 | 1` prefix), it won't.

Is there anyway around it? w/o typing the whole number?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the +1 prefix is used by more countries than just the United States. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed it's a Pigeonhole principle case.

Decided to use the first viable option:

```
const countryCallingCode = e.target.value;
const asYouType = new AsYouType();
asYouType.input(`+${countryCallingCode}`);

let currentCountyCode = asYouType.country;

if (!currentCountyCode) {
    const matchingCountriesArray = asYouType.metadata.metadata.country_calling_codes[
        countryCallingCode
    ];

    if (matchingCountriesArray) {
        currentCountyCode = matchingCountriesArray[0];
    }
}
```